# Doctrine 1.2 class self reference in Postgres throws SQL error on save

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, yaml

I'm trying to model a user which could be invited by another user. So I set up one-to-many self reference in my doctrine model.

```
User:
  tableName: users
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(11)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    password:
      type: string(255)
    email:
      type: string(255)
    [...]
    invited_by:
      type: integer(11)
  relations:
    Inviter:
      class: User
      type: one
      local: invited_by
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Invitees
      onDelete: SET NULL
      onUpdate: CASCADE
  options:
    type: InnoDB
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8
```

This works just fine in MySQL, but if I try to save the record using the User objects save()-method in Postgres the following error is thrown:

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 FEHLER: Relation »users_id«
>   existiert nicht LINE 1: SELECT CURRVAL('users_id') ^. Failing Query:
>   "SELECT CURRVAL('users_id')"

I think it is something related to the self reference, but I can't find a mistake in my modeling. Anyone an idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default name of a sequence attached to a [serial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column is `tablename_colname_seq`
[`currval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html) is for retrieving the "current value" of a sequence.
So it would have to be:

```
SELECT currval('users_id_seq')
```

Your whole syntax is obviously made out for MySQL. Things like `type: InnoDB`, `integer(11)` or `autoincrement` don't make sense in Postgres.

Comment: Doctrine ORM handles database specifics like these - If the database does not support it or it is handled another way Doctrine ignores it or does it the way the database wants it to be ;)

Comment: I set Doctrine_Core::ATTR_SEQNAME_FORMAT to %s. %s_seq is working fine thanks.